# What happened to Bess near the end of Breaking the Waves

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-the-waves

The lead character got seriously injured in the movie, and me wonders what happened. I am thinking it might the bad guys in the 'big' ship, but that is just a guess, since there was no mention of it later on... even in court.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, its the guys on the boat.  They were so rough that the other prostitutes would not go there, and tried to brutalize Bess on her first visit there.  She goes back and the next thing we know she is heading to the hospital in serious condition.

Its not explicitly shown but I think that is just because they were trying to avoid being gratuitous, I personally didn't see where there was any ambiguity as to where her injuries came from.

Comment: The ambiguity lies in that the law enforcement part of things was just ignored. Also, this was not even mentioned in court. Perhaps I should go as far as labelling this a plot hole... some carelessless on the writer's part.

Comment: One thing that gives me doubt is that she gets taken from the ship by some medical people. I would not expect the bad guys to incriminate themselves like that.

Comment: I doubt they were worried about criminal reprisals given society's view of prostitutes (which Bess was viewed as) in that time and place, and the absence of any witnesses to refute whatever story they chose to give.  Its probably been 15 years since I saw the movie though.